# What's a good development environment for Perl?

Tags: eclipse, perl, ide

I develop applications using PHP or Java and will study Perl for the first time.

For PHP and Java, there are integrated development environments such as Eclipse, and debugging environment was regulated well, but, in the case of Perl, what kind of development environment do people use?

Is there a recommended IDE?

I would prefer a free debugging environment.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As Sinan stated, there are some IDEs for Perl. [Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/) is worth a mention. It is being actively developed by the Perl community.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about Padre. Thanks for mentioning that. I'll upvote your answer in about 20 hours ;-)

Comment: "actively developed by the Perl community" means also written in Perl. This way, when you get confortable writing Perl you can fix bugs or implement feature *you* want!

Comment: This answer was okay back in 2009, but Padre has largely been abandoned since then.

Answer (score 15):

From [perlfaq3: Is there an IDE or Windows Perl Editor?](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq3.html#Is_there_an_IDE_or_W), where it looks much nicer.

If the [Padre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padre_(software)) people want their stuff in here, just add the right bits. The source lives in [my perlfaq github repo](http://github.com/briandfoy/perlfaq/tree/master). You can fork it, edit the file right in [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub), and send me a pull request.

---

Is there an IDE or Windows Perl Editor?

Perl programs are just plain text, so any editor will do.

If you're on Unix, you already have an IDE--Unix itself.  The Unix
philosophy is the philosophy of several small tools that each do one
thing and do it well.  It's like a carpenter's toolbox.

If you want an IDE, check the following (in alphabetical order, not
order of preference):

[Eclipse](http://e-p-i-c.sf.net/)

```
    The Eclipse Perl Integration Project integrates Perl
    editing/debugging with Eclipse.
```

[Enginsite](http://www.enginsite.com/)

```
    Perl Editor by EngInSite is a complete integrated development
    environment (IDE) for creating, testing, and  debugging  Perl
    scripts; the tool runs on Windows 9x/NT/2000/XP or later.
```

[Komodo](http://www.ActiveState.com/Products/Komodo/)

```
    ActiveState's cross-platform (as of October 2004, that's Windows,
    Linux, and Solaris), multi-language IDE has Perl support, including
    a regular expression debugger and remote debugging.
```

[Open Perl IDE](http://open-perl-ide.sourceforge.net/)

```
    Open Perl IDE is an integrated development environment for writing
    and debugging Perl scripts with ActiveState's ActivePerl
    distribution under Windows 95/98/NT/2000.
```

[OptiPerl](https://www.uptiv.com/free/optiperl/)

```
    OptiPerl is a Windows IDE with simulated CGI environment, including
    debugger and syntax highlighting editor.
```

[PerlBuilder](http://www.solutionsoft.com/perl.htm)

```
    PerlBuidler is an integrated development environment for Windows
    that supports Perl development.
```

[visiPerl+](http://helpconsulting.net/visiperl/)

```
    From Help Consulting, for Windows.
```

[Visual Perl](http://www.activestate.com/Products/Visual_Perl/)

```
    Visual Perl is a Visual Studio.NET plug-in from ActiveState.
```

[Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com/lookmain.html)

```
    Zeus for Window is another Win32 multi-language editor/IDE that
    comes with support for Perl
```

For editors: if you're on Unix you probably have vi or a vi clone
already, and possibly an [Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) too, so you may not need to download
anything. In any Emacs, the `cperl-mode` (<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> `cperl-mode`) gives you
perhaps the best available Perl editing mode in any editor.

If you are using Windows, you can use any editor that lets you work
with plain text, such as NotePad or WordPad.  Word processors, such as
Microsoft Word or WordPerfect, typically do not work since they insert
all sorts of behind-the-scenes information, although some allow you to
save files as "Text Only". You can also download text editors designed
specifically for programming, such as [Textpad](http://www.textpad.com/)
and [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/), among others.

If you are using [Mac OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS), the same concerns apply.  MacPerl (for Classic
environments) comes with a simple editor. Popular external editors are
[BBEdit](http://www.bbedit.com/) or [Alpha](http://www.his.com/%7Ejguyer/Alpha/Alpha8.html). [Mac OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X) users can use Unix editors as well.

[GNU Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/windows/ntemacs.html)

[MicroEMACS](http://www.microemacs.de/)

[XEmacs](http://www.xemacs.org/Download/index.html)

[Jed](http://space.mit.edu/%7Edavis/jed/)

or a vi clone such as

Elvis [FTP](ftp://ftp.cs.pdx.edu/pub/elvis/), [WWW](http://www.fh-wedel.de/elvis/)

[Vile](http://dickey.his.com/vile/vile.html)

[Vim](http://www.vim.org/)

For vi lovers in general, Windows or elsewhere: [vi](http://www.thomer.com/thomer/vi/vi.html)

[nvi](http://www.bostic.com/vi/) (available from CPAN in `src/misc/`) is
yet another vi clone, unfortunately not available for Windows, but in
Unix platforms you might be interested in trying it out, firstly
because strictly speaking it is not a vi clone, it is the real vi, or
the new incarnation of it, and secondly because you can embed Perl
inside it to use Perl as the scripting language.  nvi is not alone in
this, though: at least also vim and vile offer an embedded Perl.

The following are Win32 multilanguage editor/IDESs that support Perl:

[Codewright](http://www.borland.com/codewright/)

[MultiEdit](http://www.MultiEdit.com/)

[SlickEdit](http://www.slickedit.com/)

There is also a toyedit Text widget based editor written in Perl that
is distributed with the Tk module on CPAN.  The [ptkdb](http://ptkdb.sourceforge.net/) is a Perl/tk based debugger that acts
as a development environment of sorts.  [Perl Composer](http://perlcomposer.sourceforge.net/) is an IDE for Perl/Tk GUI
creation.

In addition to an editor/IDE you might be interested in a more powerful
shell environment for Win32.  Your options include

Bash from the [Cygwin package](http://sources.redhat.com/cygwin/)

Ksh from the [MKS Toolkit](http://www.mks.com/), or the Bourne shell
of the [U/WIN environment](http://www.research.att.com/sw/tools/uwin/)

[Tcsh](ftp://ftp.astron.com/pub/tcsh/), see also [Using csh & tcsh](http://www.primate.wisc.edu/software/csh-tcsh-book/)

[Zsh](http://www.zsh.org/)

MKS and U/WIN are commercial (U/WIN is free for educational and
research purposes), Cygwin is covered by the GNU Public License (but
that shouldn't matter for Perl use).  The Cygwin, MKS, and U/WIN all
contain (in addition to the shells) a comprehensive set of standard
UNIX toolkit utilities.

If you're transferring text files between Unix and Windows using FTP be
sure to transfer them in ASCII mode so the ends of lines are
appropriately converted.

On Mac OS the MacPerl Application comes with a simple 32k text editor
that behaves like a rudimentary IDE.  In contrast to the MacPerl
Application the MPW Perl tool can make use o Shell f the MPW itself as
an editor (with no 32k limit).

[Affrus](http://www.latenightsw.com) is a full Perl development environment with full debugger support.

[Alpha](http://www.his.com/%7Ejguyer/Alpha/Alpha8.html) is an editor, written and extensible in Tcl, that nonetheless has built in support for several popular markup and programming
languages including Perl and HTML.

[BBEdit](http://web.barebones.com/) and [BBEdit Lite](http://web.barebones.com/) are text editors for Mac OS that have a Perl sensitivity mode.

[Pepper](http://www.hekkelman.com/) and [Pe](http://www.hekkelman.com/) are programming language sensitive text editors for Mac
OS X and BeOS respectively.

Comment: +1 but I am going to humbly suggest that just a link to the FAQ would have been sufficient.

Comment: Apparently no one reads the FAQ unless you shove it down their throats. I think for those people, following a link is probably too much work.

Comment: @SinanÜnür && brian - adding a shout here for '/annick Champoux's  [`Vim::X`](https://metacpan.org/release/Vim-X) which is pretty darn neat and lets you use perl with vim in conveniently perl-ish ways.  I look forward to articles on your respective blogs ;-)

Comment: @G.Cito Thanks for the heads up. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 14):

Perl has very good debugging support. Read [perldoc perldebug](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html) for details.

There are a bunch of IDEs such as [ActiveState's Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo/), [EPIC](http://www.epic-ide.org/) etc but I prefer to combine [GVim](http://www.vim.org/) (see also [.vimrc for Perl programmers](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=540167)) with the command line. Others prefer [Emacs](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?emacs).

Answer (score 12):

Padre is getting better, but it's currently not quite up there with Komodo or EPIC.

That said, it is comparable with Ultraedit or Notepad++ at this point, less than a year after the first line of code was written.

With about 30 people actively committing, 35-40 plugins either released or in development, and translations in 20 languages, it is also moving ahead incredibly quickly.

So right now, I agree that EPIC is probably the way to go, since you've used Eclipse already.

But by this time next year it's probably going to be a different story.

Answer (score 9):

If you're already familiar with debugging in Eclipse, then the [EPIC plugin](http://www.epic-ide.org/download.php) is exactly what you're looking for.

It's got stepped debugging within the Debug perspective, like with other languages in [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)). It's not as strong as the Java support, but it's got an easier learning curve than e.g. "perl -d" (the 'standard' way to debug Perl), or even learning a new editor like Emacs, with its Perl debugging integration.

Answer (score 6):

What I use -- and what I've gotten the impression that most other serious Perl developers use -- is a good *text editor*. The only "integration" I have is via user-defined tools. For Perl, that's these:

```
perl -Mstrict -cw <file>  # Perl "lint"
perl <file>               # run file
perl -d <file>            # run file in debugger
```

I have others for checking files in/out of version control, browsing history, etc. A good configurable editor (I'm partial to [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com)) will allow you to build your own environment using the tools you want instead of foisting an all-encompassing solution on you.

Answer (score 4):

[Komodo Edit](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/) is a free editor from Active State, probably not as feature rich as the full IDE but I find it very useful for Perl development, and it supports multiple languages.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify which platform you're on, but on the [Macintosh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh), TextMate is a very popular choice for Perl development. It's completely replaced [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)) for me, and while it's not a full IDE, it's got alot of neat integrations in bundles specially targeted towards Perl development.